# CosmosDB C# Gremlin - Getting exception when sending query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet

Am getting a exception on the .wait() part:

```
   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.Connection.ReceiveAsync[T]()
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.Connection.SubmitAsync[T](RequestMessage requestMessage)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ProxyConnection.SubmitAsync[T](RequestMessage requestMessage)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.GremlinClient.SubmitAsync[T](RequestMessage requestMessage)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.GremlinClientExtensions.SubmitAsync[T](IGremlinClient gremlinClient, String requestScript, Dictionary`2 bindings)
```

Code:

```
    private static string database = "db";
    private static string collection = "col";                                             
    private static string hostname = "grem-test.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com";
    public void test()
    {
        var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(hostname, 443, enableSsl: true,
                                                username: "/dbs/" + database + "/colls/" + collection,
                                                password: authKey);
        var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer);
        var grem = "g.V()";
        var t = gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(grem);
        t.Wait();

        foreach (var result in t.Result)
        {
            // The vertex results are formed as dictionaries with a nested dictionary for their properties
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\tResult:\n\t{0}", output));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
    var task = gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(grem);
    task.Wait();
```

Taken from Gremlin C# Samples:

```
                 // Create async task to execute the Gremlin query.
                var task = gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(query.Value);
                task.Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, but unless I am missing something, that’s exactly what I am doing - only difference I am using “var t” instead of “var task”.

Comment: Also, lookIng at the stack trace, error is in the receive.

Comment: Cloning the sample application runs ok. So I tried again from scratch trying to match the config of the sample - I started with File->New .Net 4.62 console app, then I (is it nugot or nugetted? :) ) Gremlin.net rc 3.4 + NewtonsoftJson. Now I get "SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" in the "t.Wait()" command.

Comment: I realize the variable = t versus variable = task but, something might be hard coded in the tutorial. It is always the best place to start...use the tutorial as-is...and then reverse engineer. As for nuget, this is the Visual Studio/.NET package manager.

Comment: After using VS for many many years, I am familiar with nuget. I was turning it into a verb and wondering what the past tense would be.

Comment: Regardless, I can’t File->New a project that will work with CosmosDB.

Comment: Let me investigate this.

Comment: So, this is really a use case with Cosmos DB client examples and doing new (related) projects in Visual Studio. Please Up Vote and Comment on the following User Voice post: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/35621032-better-tooling-for-gremlin-in-visual-studio

Comment: You may reach out to: askcosmosdb at Microsoft com to present this use case and see if there are any templates or resources that they can provide you in the mean time.

Comment: Has anyone fixed this `socketexception` ? If so, can you share the answer please.

Comment: I have created a .Net Core project from scratch with Gremlin.NET v3.4.0 and I can setup the connection without socketexception, but any query I send to the server ends up in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I have no idea how to move forward and will now look for an alternative to Azure for Graph DB...

Answer (score 0):

I started with the sample application where it uses:

```
        private static Task<ResultSet<dynamic>> SubmitRequest(GremlinClient gremlinClient, string query)
        {
            try
            {
                return gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(query);
            }
            catch (ResponseException e)
            {
                // They have extra stuff here for the request information that isn't relevant
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I expanded from there and never had any issues besides the occasional exception from trying to run a query while another one was still working. I can only assume that running the queries this way works better than directly calling SubmitAsync().

One other thing I would recommend is double-checking your values for the server parameters just in case.

Comment: can you post your expanded solution here? How did you fix it. I also used the sample but I still get errors